# What is Spring REST url of my controller?

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I building rest application from scratch and I just create basic rest controller and I want to try if it works.

Here it is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String poll(@RequestParam Long messageId) {
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

I tried it in browser on this url:
http://localhost:8080/api/test?messageId=61

but I got error 404

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Apr 25 21:23:35 CEST 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Can you tell me what is correct url for this rest controller? Thanks.

EDIT 1:
this is from log so port is also ok:

```
Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
```

EDIT 2:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

Comment: When you start your application, you should also see all the URL mappings, which were detected by Spring, in the logfile. Check if your endpoint is there or not.

Comment: yes, they will printed Mapped "{[/api/test],methods=[GET]}"

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot do you have? I've tested your code on 1.5.8 and it runs.

Comment: @AdamLesiak Thanks for your effort, I am using 2.01

Comment: Hm... in 2.0.1 also working event copy-paste your code :). Can you put code from your configuration file? application.properites or application.yml.

Comment: @AdamLesiak sure, check my updated question, but I got there just datasource configuration

Comment: Strange and stranger... In your configuration there is nothing for server/context/path configuration. Check where you store the MyController class and move it to the same path (package) where main class in stored. Main I mean class with @SpringBootApplication annotation and restart app.

Comment: still not works :/ I have  put controllers into ./web/xxxController.java
I have also here another one which works fine :/

Comment: Can you edit the qs with your project structure

Answer (score 0):

Try `public String poll(@RequestParam("messageId") Long messageId) {`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed your project name here:

```
http://localhost:8080/[PROJECT_NAME]/api/test?messageId=61
```

Comment: But context path is ' '.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve got to possible theories here:

**Cause 1:**  From my experience, I´m used to make it work this way: For the @GetMapping Annotation I would type

`@GetMapping("/test/{messageId}")`

And then I would change your method to:

```
public String poll(@PathVariable Long messageId){...}
```

**Cause 2:** I think the url should be http://localhost:8080/api/test?**61**

I hope it helps, in case neither soulution works, I encourage you to test them out together.